Scaling a N-body-simulation and error tolerances
When doing a N-body simulation, one could scale it and if done right I would expect identical behavior just on different time-scales and sizes (with minor differences due to rounding errors). If I for example place particles in a cube of size 10 and (with adjusted speeds) in a cube of size 1, I should get a smaller and faster system that is otherwise identical. This requires smaller step sizes (which are automatically chosen by the solver anyway), but it should overall take the same number of steps to get the same scaled results.
With ODE45 in Matlab I get unusable small step-sizes with the smaller system, which forces me to increase the error tolerances. But I don't know how relTol and absTol relate here. In ODE45 absTol/relTol give a threshold which is used in the calculation of the maximum error. With the bigger system the standard error-tolerances (relTol = 1e-3, absTol = 1e-6, so threshold = 1e-3) work fine. I also got good results if I change these error-tolerances by the same factor, so threshold stays the same.
But with a scaled system, I suspect that threshold should also change and thus the ratio absTol/relTol. But I have no idea by what amount (or at all). For the small system going to relTol = absTol = 1 seems to work, but I want to make sure that this is equivalent to the bigger system.
Can someone give me some insights on how to scale the error tolerances? Would it make sense, in the context of a N-body-simulation, to just use one of these error-tolerances (and set the other one arbitrarily high)?

Isn't the entire point of a N-body simulation to illustrate that simulations like this are chaotic in nature and minuscule tolerance mistakes (beyond what is humanly/computationally tractable) will create a wildly different result? i.e. are you not just asking "how to ignore chaos theory"?

Of course there will be rounding errors that will/can result in wildly different results. But the point of numerical simulations is to get as close to the truth as possible. Mathematically (so with infinite precision and time steps) I think it should be possible to shrink a system and get a perfect analogous system. One chooses the error tolerances so that the result is reasonably correct with reasonable runtime. My question is: How do relTol and absTol scale with the system. That has nothing to do with chaos and the same question could be applied to any differential equation...

Right, but the entire point of chaos theory is that you can say mathematically whatever you want, in practice you will never be able to simulate it. At some point you need a tolerance of 1e-(e^100000000000)), so its meaningless to try to do it. Note that the same question can be applied to any differential equation, but some differential equations will give you the same answer I gave you, while others are easily solvable numerically. I don't know if its knowable how to scale the tolerances (which is why I didn't answer the question) but even if its possible, it would be at least exponential.

As I see it: Every numerical approach is always an approximation. And thus scaling the system will give different results. But still: The same way my, say, 4th-order-method will (up to a certain point) converge to the real solution with O(h^4) it should be possible to say: "If I scale down my system by a factor of 2, I will have to increase my relTol by X and my absTol by Y to get comparable results with comparable effort". All that of course only to a certain point (simulating masses that are lightyears apart over millions of years might fail because of cancellation if I don't scale down)

Can you produce maybe a small example with code that demonstrates the issue and post that? It is hard to advise you unless we see exactly how you scaled the problem and how large the differences are and how fast they are growing.
